# TDateTimePicker with Kind=dtkDate returning time fraction in Date property?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, datetimepicker

I have a TDateTimePicker with Kind=dtkDate on my form.
When the form opens I do

```
TDateTimePicker.date := Date
```

I have a `var lStartDay : TDateTime;` and do

```
lStartDay := DatePickerStart.Date;
```

I have not touched the TDateTimePicker in the user interface.

Now, the evaluate/modify (Ctrl-F7) dialog and the watch list (and the cursor hovering over the code) show DatePickerStart.Date as 8-1-2014, but StartDate is 8-1-2014 15:00:00

When I edit the watch value DatePickerStart.Date to **not use the visualizer** it shows 41647,625 (it took me some time to find that!)

Why does TDateTimePicker.Date contain a time fraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question to prevent others from tumbling into the same pit:

It turns out that when you place a TDateTimePicker on your form, the Time property gets filled with the current time **and this always gets returned as part of DatePickerStart.Date**. Mine was obviously placed on the form at 15:00:00

The time remains 'in' even when you use the TDateTimePicker so select another date.

So, to fix this: Clear the Time property at design time (it becomes 00:00:00) and/or always use Trunc(TDateTimePicker.Date) or DateOf(TDateTimePicker.Date) when you really only need the date.

Of itself, **TDateTimePicker.Date does not return the date!**.

Comment: I prefer to use `ReplaceTime(TDateTimePicket.Date, 0.0)` and `ReplaceDate(TDateTimePicker.Time, 0.0)`.

Comment: This bug has been around for over a decade (probably since its introduction). I wrote an article about this very thing in the UK BUG magazine way back in 1998/1999.